# SQL Joint query for unmatched rows in left table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, join

I got two tables,sfuser and membership

sfuser got 139 and membership table got 50

I need the query to pick who are not a member of any project which means 89 members

Here is my query

```
select sfuser.id,sfuser.username,sfuser.email from sfuser INNER JOIN projectmembership ON sfuser.id = projectmembership.member_id ;
```

But am getting the 50 users who are members i want the other way around

Kindly throw some light

Best Regards
Sathish

Answer (score 4):

```
select 
sfuser.id,
sfuser.username,
sfuser.email 
from sfuser 
LEFT JOIN projectmembership ON sfuser.id = projectmembership.member_id
WHERE 
projectmembership.member_id is NULL
```

It should return all users that isn't in projectmembership table.

Comment: Thanks a lot darius and abhik

Answer (score 1):

INNER JOIN will only produce rows that matches both tables.. You can do a left join and filter out the blank records. something like:

```
SELECT sfuser.id,
sfuser.username,
sfuser.email
FROM sfuser LEFT JOIN projectmembership ON sfuser.id = projectmembership.member_id
WHERE (projectmembership.member_id is null);
```

Answer (score 1):

An inner join will return all rows where the values the join is done on are shared between the two tables. (See [this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ5XP.png))

What you are looking for is a left join, that is, all rows in the left table that have no match in the right.

```
select sfuser.id,
  sfuser.username,
  sfuser.email 
from sfuser 
LEFT JOIN projectmembership 
  ON sfuser.id = projectmembership.member_id
```

Answer (score 1):

If sfuser records can have multiple occurrences in the project membership table then forget the outer join -- NOT EXISTS is what you want:

```
select sid,
       username,
       email
from   sfuser
where  not exists (
         select null
         from   projectmembership
         where  sfuser.id = projectmembership.member_id);
```